# Worksheet_Change Event not firing using wireless scanner

Tags: excel, vba, barcode

I am scanning barcode using honeywell laser USB device to read the barcode and it triggers the Worksheet_Change event and works fine.

But if I am using Honeywell Wireless 1452G series device and read the barcode, it doesn't trigger the Worksheet_Change event.

Please help!! as I am stuck into this from past 1 week.

Comment: The scanner must be set to also send 'Enter'...

Answer (score 1):

What a scanner normally does is simulating keystrokes send to the computer. Excel itself does not know anything about the fact that (or which) scanner send the keystrokes, so the behavior shouldn't change.

Your problem most likely comes from the fact that the HoneyWell scanner sends only the content of the barcode, but doesn't finish the entry by sending an `Enter` or `Tab`-character. Without that, Excel stays within the cell, waiting for more input to come - exactly the same as if you type something in the cell but don't leave it. The `Worksheet_Change` fires only after the entry is complete.

Basically, you need to change the config of you scanner - this is not an Excel or VBA issue.

Comment: Thomas: Thanks,Yes you are right. I had to configure my scanners by scanning the enter line and carriage return barcodes.